# Getting "The client failed to request" exception while reading Firefox URL using NDde

Tags: c#, url, firefox

I am getting following exception.

> NDde.DdeException: The client failed to request
>   "Firefox|WWW_GetWindowInfo!URL". ---> NDde.Foundation.DdemlException:
>   The client failed to request "Firefox|WWW_GetWindowInfo!URL".

Code I am using is

```
using NDde.Client;
.
.
.


 DdeClient dde = new DdeClient("Firefox", "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
                dde.Connect();
                retVal = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
                dde.Disconnect();
                MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(retVal, "\"([^\"]*)\"");
                if (match.Count > 0)
                {
                    retVal = match[0].Value.Replace(@"""", string.Empty);
                }
```

If I call above code from two different plugins I am getting issue. If I disable one plugin Its working fine.

Need help.

Comment: The Firefox isn't allowing multiple simultaneous connections from the same client to prevent Service Attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right we have decided to write common code to get URL information.

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox isn't allowing multiple simultaneous connections from the same client.